# Why is UIBarButtonItem resizing when I click it?

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I click this UIBarButtonItem which has a unicode title to display a cog symbol, it resizes and becomes smaller. Here's the code:

```swift
let settings = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSString(string: "\u{2699}\u{0000FE0E}") as String, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(show_settings))
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : font]
settings.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Heres how it looks like when I click it:
[image: UIBarButtonItem resize bug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set TitleAttributes for highlighted state as well as below:

```
 let settings = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSString(string: "\u{2699}\u{0000FE0E}") as String, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(show_settings))
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : font]
        settings.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        settings.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .highlighted)
```

[image]

Hope this will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you set attributes **only** for *normal* state

```
settings.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Comment: I tried `settings.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: [.normal, .disabled, .focused, .highlighted, .selected])` but I still get the same result. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     settings.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 28];
```

or Swift

```
    settings.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
```

I think the problem is that you are using this attribute for normal, and max be the default size overrides it when you click on it. I'm not sure but the line above should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
settings.setTitleTextAttributes(
            [
                NSAttributedStringKey.font :UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28) ,
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue
            ],
            for: .normal)
```